# Return initial jqXHR from $.ajax.then

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsgrid

My original task is the following:

1. Execute jQuery.ajax()
2. On success, do some extra checks on the data returned by the server
3. If these checks fail, return a rejected promise.

After googling and stackoverflowing, the following solution was born:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some url",
  data: somedata,
  error: somefunction
}).then(function (data) {
  if (!ajaxSuccess(data, null, null)) {
      return new $.Deferred().reject().promise();
  }
  return data;
});
```

(Function ajaxSuccess does perform the checks mentioned above in paragraph 2.)

What I dislike about this code is the last line:

```
return data;
```

IMHO, it would be much more correct to return the original ajax jqXHR object, since the result of the code will be used by a third-party library js-Grid.com, which expects a jqXHR/promise.

So the questions are:

1. Is it more correct to return the original ajax jqXHR rather than parsed JSON?
2. How to return the original jqXHR?

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

1. opinions are irrelevant - do what you require for your code
2. jQuery has a very loose interpretation of how Promises work, especially with AJAX family of functions, the callback function passed to `.then` actually receives THREE arguments

So, you could do:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some url",
  data: somedata,
  error: somefunction
}).then(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  if (!ajaxSuccess(data, null, null)) {
      return new $.Deferred().reject().promise();
  }
  return jqXHR;
});
```